# Timeout when using "encrypt: true" for SQL Server connection using mssql module

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I am using the [mssql node.js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to connect with SQL Server 2005.

It used to work fine when I started, with version 1.1.0 however when I upgraded today to the new version (3.3.0) it stopped working and started throwing Connection Timeout errors.

After some trial and error, I found that if I remove the `encrypt: true` from the options, it works.

I would still like to have the connection encrypted, so wonder if anyone can explain why this happens, and if there is any way to fix this?

The code which is failing is essentially this:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    // Add database connection
    var connection = new sql.Connection(sqlConfig: {
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'IP address',
        database: 'database name',
        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('Connection error: ' + err.message);
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        else {
            req.connection = connection;
            next();
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

The error I get is:

> Connection error: Failed to connect to [server IP]:1433 in 15000ms

Comment: same issue.. any solution?\

Comment: @PrasanthJaya no, sorry, Since our application isn't really secure to begin with, I simply don't use encrypt: true since then.